# SQLSRV driver installation problem in Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit system

Tags: drivers, software-installation, php, compiling, mssql

I'm trying to install sqlsrv driver in my Ubuntu 16.04 os system, but I get this error

```
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootliPAYQ/sqlsrv-4.3.0/libtool 
--mode=compile g++ -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootliPAYQ/sqlsrv-4.3.0/include 
-I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootliPAYQ/sqlsrv-4.3.0/main  
-I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include
/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include
/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include
/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 
-I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector   -c /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv
/conn.cpp -o conn.lo

 libtool: compile:  g++ -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootliPAYQ/sqlsrv-4.3.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootliPAYQ/sqlsrv-4.3.0/main 

-I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/
main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/
lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 
-I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/ 
-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/
temp/sqlsrv/conn.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/conn.o In file included from /tmp/pear/
temp/sqlsrv/shared/xplat.h:99:0,
from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/typedefs_for_linux.h:23,
from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/xplat_winnls.h:24,
from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/FormattedPrint.h:24,
from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/core_sqlsrv.h:41,
from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/php_sqlsrv.h:25,
from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/conn.cpp:20:
/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/xplat_intsafe.h:50:29: error: conflicting declaration 
‘typedef windowsULong_t DWORD’
 typedef windowsULong_t      DWORD;
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/sql.h:19:0,
             from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/xplat.h:30,
             from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/typedefs_for_linux.h:23,
             from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/xplat_winnls.h:24,
             from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/FormattedPrint.h:24,
             from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/core_sqlsrv.h:41,
             from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/php_sqlsrv.h:25,
             from /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/conn.cpp:20:
/usr/include/sqltypes.h:96:24: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef long     unsigned int DWORD’
typedef unsigned long  DWORD;
                    ^
Makefile:194: recipe for target 'conn.lo' failed
make: *** [conn.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

How can I solve this problem? Please note this, my PHP version is 7.0.22 and os is ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS ).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please edit your question to (at least) include a link to the sources your are using and the procedure you are following (if any).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto It may be this source: [PECL::Package::sqlsrv::4.3.0](https://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv/4.3.0). Although I don't know for sure, meanwhile I'm voting to leave this question open until shijin provides a definite link to the source. The linked GitHub webpage says that it's compatible with PHP 7.

Comment: i'm trying to use this commands- sudo pecl install sqlsrv

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto my PHP version is  7.0.22-0 and os is ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )

Answer (score 6):

You should follow the official installation instructions from Microsoft.

See: [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) (also [PDF manual](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55642)).

The following steps are copied from the guide:

## Step 1. Install PHP

```
sudo su 
apt-get update 
apt-get -y install php7.0 mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt php-mbstring php-pear php7.0-dev 
php7.0-xml
```

## Step 2. Install prerequisites

```
sudo su 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
exit 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql mssql-tools 
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev 
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile 
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc 
source ~/.bashrc
```

## Step 3. Install the PHP drivers for Microsoft SQL Server

```
sudo pear config-set php_ini `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"` system 
sudo pecl install sqlsrv 
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

Comment: when i'm trying to this command 'sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql mssql-tools', this errors will come, E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql
E: Unable to locate package mssql-tools

Comment: @shijin please verify if the repository has been added correctly.

Comment: I'm following your steps, Step1 is in newest versions, but in step 2 i'm failed with this command- 'sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql mssql-tools'. This errors look like, E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql E: Unable to locate package mssql-tools

Comment: @shijin OK but please check if the repository has been added correctly by the curl commands written before the failing command.

Comment: @ Andrea Lazzarotto, Yes, curl commands working perfectely. Out put of first curl operation is - 'Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   983  100   983    0     0    660      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   660
OK', and out put of second curl operation is - ' % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    79  100    79    0     0     60      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    60'

Comment: @ Andrea Lazzarotto any sggestion? please help me?

Comment: i solve this problem. Thank you for valuable comments.....

Comment: @shijin was there any needed step that wasn't covered in the answer?

Comment: i use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860273/laravel-to-sql-server-sqlsrv-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver  for solving this problem.

Comment: @shijin good. Then please post a self-answer and reference the link there too. :)

Comment: Your steps 2 & 3 have some lines wrapped into the next row, which would cause issues when running by simple copy/paste

Comment: @shijin msodbcsql and mssql-tools are only available for 64Bits but you are running Ubuntu 32 bits

Comment: @Angel115 we can install mssql-tool in 32 bit.  sorry i forgot that link.

Comment: Use http not https for the repository url or you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above works if you add the following:

## change 7.x in the following to your current version  ls /etc/php/  to find it

echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/7.x/apache2/php.ini
echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/7.x/apache2/php.ini